# How do I get the android emulator to use port 1900 when it's already being used by Windows?

Tags: android, android-emulator, upnp

I'm writing an android application that searches for devices using the UPnP port 1900, but when I telnet into the emulator and try to set up the port redirect like so:

```
redir add udp:1900:1900
```

It says:

```
Can't setup redirection, port probably used by another program on host
```

Port 1900 is being used on my computer by the Microsoft Plug and Play service and apparently cannot be disabled.

Is there any way around this? Short of side loading the apk on every change, what options do I have to test while developing?

I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The emulator forwards only listen on the development machine's internal interface anyway, so only test code running on the development machine could directly contact it.  As a result, your best bet is probably to forward it from a different port and customize the test code to contact it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to disable the SSDP Discovery Service in services. This freed up port 1900 and the above emulator redirection command now works. Even though this service will restart when I restart the system, it will allow me to debug and test via the emulator.